# What was the name of Sarah's mother?

Tags: history, names, imahot-matriarch-mothers, sarah

Seder Hadoros mentions Avraham's mother, how old Nachor was when Sarah was born, and even a Peshat that Lot was her brother, though no mention of Sarah's mother's name. Any other sources that mention it?

Comment: See [Hebrew Wikipedia –
_שמות חיצוניים לדמויות אנונימיות במקרא_
:
_אם שרה אימנו_](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90#.D7.90.D7.9D_.D7.A9.D7.A8.D7.94_.D7.90.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.95)

Comment: apparently, R' Chaim Kanievski writes that her name was טסה. Anyone got a source for that? Supposed to be in למכסה עתיק..

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47477

Answer (score 3):

As @Zvi mentioned it is mentioned in the Sefer למכסה עתיק (Rav Chaim Kanievski)that Sarah's name was Yiska Bas Tissa(not sure pronunciation).

[image]

This is the footnote 44:

[image]