# What was Avraham Avinu's mother's name?

Tags: names, women, avot-patriarch-fathers, historical-figures, abraham

What was Avraham Avinu's mother's name?

Our shul received a paper with questions on Simhat Torah, with this question being one of the harder ones. Is there a midrash on her name?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38586

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Her name was אמתלאי בת כרנבו.

> ואמר רב חנן בר רבא אמר רב **אמיה דאברהם אמתלאי בת כרנבו** אמיה דהמן אמתלאי
>   בת עורבתי וסימניך טמא טמא טהור טהור

Bava Basra [91a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=91&format=pdf)

(*I knew it existed, but will admit to having resorted to Google to find it fast.*)

Comment: Now, who's כרנבו?

Comment: @Scimonster :-)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48497/5323

Answer (score 1):

[Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 26:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.26.3?with=all&lang=bi) says that Avraham Avinu's mother was עתדיי (Ataday? not sure how to pronounce it):

הנס השלישי, טלטולו מבית אביו ומארץ מולדתו והביאו לחרן ושם מת תרח אביו ועתדיי אמו והטלטול קשה לאדם יותר מכל ומניין טלטולו, שנאמר ויאמר ה' אל אברם לך לך.